# sql: select where problem with null value

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause, sql-null

students table:

```
id          name
0           NULL
1           John
```

Query:

```
SELECT * from students WHERE name != "John";
```

Expected output:

```
0           NULL
```

With my test, the result is empty, how i can solve this?

```
SELECT * from students WHERE name != "John" OR name == NULL;
```

[image: screen]

Comment: It should be noted, that for calculation purposes, NULL is treated as a missing value, not as a value itself. As such, when SQL is trying to say whether or not NULL == "John", it has no idea, because the value's 'missing'. As such, if NULL has a particular meaning in your dataset, you will need to specify. Better yet, if you are able to, create a flag in your table to differentiate between missing values and otherwise meaningful NULL values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, you want:

```
SELECT * from students WHERE name <> 'John' or name is null
```

Assuming that you are running MySQL, as your screen copy suggests, you could also express with the `null`-safe operator

```
SELECT * from students WHERE NOT name <=> 'John'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, `NULL` is not value so you cannot compare using `=`. take a look at [DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9t6sSUjTiN27fZDHixrcyq/1)

```
SELECT * from students WHERE name != 'John' and name is NULL;
```

This is a good [read](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/18/why-null-never-compares-false-to-anything-in-sql/).

Comment: but, I want to use `!=`, my purpose is except `john`

Comment: @KingStone You can use it, I have updated my answer.